# Getting cfr-lm and titlesec to work together

Tags: titlesec, oldstylenums

In my minimal example below, I would like to use the cfr-lm package to make all numbers oldstylenums, but use bold with small caps in the titles.

I use pdflatex with TexMaker as my frontend.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[
    left = 2cm, 
    right = 2.5cm, 
    top = 1.5cm, 
    bottom = 2cm
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


%\titleformat{\section}{\Large\sc\bfseries}{}{0cm}{}[\titlerule]
%\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\bfseries\sc}{}{0cm}{}[ --]
%\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries\sc}{}{0cm}{}


%\renewcommand{\labelitemi}{--}
%\newcommand{\tabitem}{\makebox[0pt][r]{--}}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\huge\scshape\bfseries}{{\chaptertitlename}~{\thechapter}}{10pt}{\Huge}
\titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\bfseries}{\thesection}{0.5cm}{}[\titlerule]
\titleformat{\subsection}{\large\bfseries\scshape}{\thesubsection}{0.5cm}{}
\titleformat{\subsubsection}{\bfseries\scshape}{}{0cm}{}[]


%Manipulation of headers and footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
%Clear fields
\fancyhf{}
%Page numbering in footer
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
%Separation line header and footer
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center}
\Huge \textbf{\textsc{Eating\hspace{0.5cm}Foods}}
\end{center}

\section{How to eat food}
Food is important
\subsection{Using hands}
Most versatile. I have 2 hands.
\subsection{Using chopsticks}
Requires practice. I have 54 chopsticks.
\subsection{Using spoons}
Kind of a middle ground. Around 55 spoons were kept in 14 boxes.
\subsubsection{Types of spoons}
There are many types of spoons. I have 4 types of spoons

\end{document}
```

I find that when I comment out the cfr-lm package, I get the titles in the correct format, but lose the fancy numbering format. How to make these two work together?

Comment: The cfr-lm package does not define bold small caps, methinks.

Comment: Small caps already show emphasis; double emphasis ie evil.